# how to print odd numbered observations from a dataset SAS

Tags: printing, dataset, sas, subset

I have a simple question, that I unfortunately cannot seem to solve myself.
How to print only observations with an odd observation number from a data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you might do this is with a data step view.  Assuming you have a data set named "MySASData", try this:

```
data my_view / view=my_view;
   set MySASData;
   if mod(_n_,2) = 1;
run;
proc print data=my_view;
run;
```

If you wanted "even" observations, you use `if mod(_n_,2) = 0;`.  However, note that the observation numbers displayed by `proc print` will be relative to the view and not from the original data set.

Data step views are very useful for things like this.